# setting the state inside the useEffect with that state as a dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, use-state

Let's say I have this code here:

```
const [a , setA] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
      setA(true);

    setTimeout(()=>{
      setA(false);
    },300);

},[a]);
```

I have two questions:

**1)** Will this create an infinte loop (if I'm using that same state as a dependency)?

**2)** If I set the state **in the middle** of the useEffect code the component re-render immediately, so when will the rest of the code  execute if the component render before we get to it inside the useEffect?
When will the `setA(false)` happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix the syntax (`setTimeOut` needs to be spelled properly), yes, that'll cause an infinite loop.

```js
const App = () => {
    console.log('rendering');
    const [a , setA] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
          setA(true);

        setTimeout(()=>{
          setA(false);
        },300);

    },[a]);
    return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

> If I set the state in the middle of the useEffect code the component re-render immediately, so when will the rest of the code execute if the component render before we get to it inside the useEffect? When will the setA(false) happen?

It'll occur just as it was originally scheduled to - 300-ish milliseconds after the hook originally runs. When the component re-mounts, it will not cancel or change ongoing timeouts that previous renders might have created, unless you've specifically written code to handle that possibility.

1. The component mounts or has `setA` called
2. The component (re-)renders
3. The effect hook runs
4. If the effect hook eventually calls `setTimeout`, the timeout callback will run regardless, exactly at the time scheduled, no matter what other code there is - as long as you don't call `clearTimeout`. If you set state as well as calling `setTimeout`, that has no effect on the timeout. (which is an important thing to keep in mind - stale closures are a common problem people run into with React)

Comment: But what if I don't use the setTimeout? is this the order of how it works when the state changes: 

1. useEffect runs because of that change.

2. setA is re-rendering the component.

3. the rest of the code is executed after that.(because it was queued)

4. we have an infinte loop because now the state has changed again...                

And can you explain in more details how that clearTimeout works?

Comment: What do you mean, don't use the setTimeout? If you mean you *want* to clear it under certain circumstances, then you'll need to call `clearTimeout` on the timeout ID from it. The re-render only occurs after the effect hook finishes running - it's asynchronous.

Comment: So, you're saying that the re-rendering happanes **after** the useEffect runs? so is that means the component will re-render twice after? for each time we called the setA?

Comment: Yes, state setters result in components re-rendering, and re-rendering is asynchronous.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Thanks for that detailed answer! You realy helped me clear my doubts about this.

Answer (score 1):

> If I set the state in the middle of the useEffect code the component re-render immediately, so when will the rest of the code execute if the component render before we get to it inside the useEffect? When will the setA(false) happen?

No, It will not re-render the component in middle of useEffect even if you set the state. useState hook runs asynchronously. It will be queued.